# How to double buffer svg in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've a svg which is loaded from CGI and it needs to be refresh per 5 sec.
The problem is, it takes time to load CGI generated svg content and when it was loading, my container div becomes empty and after loading image comes back. 
This "wink" is annoying..
How to double buffer it? I tried a second div with z-index -1 and hidden behind. But it seems when I flip it to front it does not re-render and leave me an empty div.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a new image element, set it's onload handler to add it to the page (replace the old one) when it's loaded, then finally set the source of the image to be the url of your cgi?

Comment: It works fine with img tag. The thing is, it is an interactive svg and has to stay inside of object tag. The trick does not work for object tag and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of z-index why not try flipping to/from visibility:hidden or to/from display:none changing these should force a re-render.

Comment: I believe SVGs on display:none elements won't get loaded until the element is made visible.  I would expect that visibility:hidden will work though.

Comment: Right, I tried display:none and svg is not loaded. I didn't tried visibility yet. I will give it a try. Thx.

Comment: Any results from this?